# why the normal counter runs only last setCount argument and functional counter runs all setCount?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

Why the first one is only running the last setCount argument and when we are using the arrow function for setCount it's running both the argument.

eg: if you click the Normal button the *count* will be **5** as it should be **9**
If you click the Functional button the *count* will be **2** as it is running both the SetCount

```
import react, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
 const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
 console.log(count);
 return (
   <div className="App">
     <button
       onClick={() => {
         setCount(count + 1);
         setCount(count + 3);
         setCount(count + 5);
       }}
     >
       Normal
     </button>
     <br />

     <button
       onClick={() => {
         setCount((c) => c + 1);
         setCount((c) => c + 1);
       }}
     >
       Functional
     </button>
   </div>
 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when we use parameter set value once

**current value set on the count and run 3 methods with parameters**

```
setCount(count + 1);
setCount(count + 3);
setCount(count + 5);
```

but in this case :
`setCount((c) => c + 1);`
when (c) => c + 1 method called c get the current value each time

Answer (score 0):

Your "normal" code captures the current state value of count in a closure. The first time your component is rendered this basically boils donw to following:

```
() => {
    setCount(0 + 1);
    setCount(0 + 3);
    setCount(0 + 5);
}
```

As state updates are batched the last one wins, so the resulting state value is 5.

The "Functional" code sample uses the callback `Dispatch`, that provides you with the previous value of state at the time your change happens, not affected by closures. Basically:

```
() => {
    setCount((0) => 0 + 1);
    setCount((1) => 1 + 1);
}
```

Both have their uses, depends on what you want.

Answer (score 0):

When computing the sum of values, in your case, calculating 9 from the sum of 1, 3 and 5, we need pass a function to `setCount` with the parameter being the previous value

```
setCount((c) => c + 1); // previous count is 0, new count is 1
setCount((c) => c + 3); // previous count is 1, new count is 4
setCount((c) => c + 5); // previous count is 5, new count is 9
```

This is documented in official doccs:

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates

> If the new state is computed using the previous state, you can pass a function to setState. The function will receive the previous value, and return an updated value.

Comment: It was very helpful in explaining the whole concept at a glance.